# How to access elmah Url in azure websites?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, elmah

I just created a simple sharepoint asp.net mvc app with ELMAH included, locally I could see the errors, on the url /Elmah.

However when I package it and publish it to azure, then I get this error:
You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Which I believe its normal because its not a local IIS site.

As an administrator or developer, how could I access this page after deployed to production?
Is there something I can do in web.config to allow this page to be viewable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't set it up on Azure before, but typically you visit url/elmah.axd instead of url/elmah.

Secondly, yes, you can add:

```
<security allowRemoteAccess="true" />
```

to the web.config settings for ELMAH in order to allow you to view the log after it's deployed. Understand though that by default it will allow anyone else to view the logs as well.

Comment: Is that setting for elmah MVC or the prior versions?